# How to remove data from fractal library

Tags: php, laravel, thephpleague-fractal

I'm using laravel 8 and [fractal](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-fractal) library.
I want to remove `data` property result of fractal with `DataArraySerializer`:

```
use League\Fractal\Serializer\DataArraySerializer;

class TransformerSerializer extends DataArraySerializer
{
    public function collection($resourceKey, array $data)
    {
        return $data;
    }

    public function item($resourceKey, array $data)
    {
        return $data;
    }
}
```

my cocde:

```
    $tickets = Ticket::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->orderBy('id','desc')->paginate();

    $reulst = fractal()
        ->collection($tickets->getCollection())
        ->transformWith(new TicketTransformer())
        ->parseIncludes(['user.profile','status','service'])
        ->paginateWith(new IlluminatePaginatorAdapter($tickets));
```

But the result is:

```
{
"0":{},
"1":{}
}
```

but I want to have this result:

```
[
{},
{}
]
```

Comment: I don't know about this Fractal library, but could you just use `array_values()` on the result array?

Comment: @miken32 with this solution `meta` key is removed. the `meta` key is about pagination.

Comment: I don't see a "meta" key in your provided result.